# Excel 2003 Spreadsheet Object Disappears in Excel 2007

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-2003, vba

I've inherited an old Excel 2003 application, and need to convert it so that it works in Excel 2007. The application makes use of a spreadsheet as a "popup" inside the application for doing volume calculations. In Excel 2003, this works as expected. In Excel 2007, VBA complains with an "Object Required" error.

Browsing through the Object Browser, Excel 2003 lists "VolSheet" as a Spreadsheet object. Excel 2007 can't find it at all. Excel 2007 *does* list "VolSheet" as a Shape if you loop through all shapes (ActiveSheet.Shapes), however.

My question is: Is there a way to force Excel 2007 to recognize VolSheet as a spreadsheet? Would I have to Dim it somewhere and find a way to convert the Shape reference to a spreadsheet? Can I trick Excel 2007 into recognizing that it does in fact already exist inside one of the Worksheets?

Comment: I'm afraid VolSheet is something specific to your solution so it's a bit hard to debug with this info. What's the specific line of code that fails, and are there any references missing (Tools..References in the VBA editor)?

Comment: It is possible that VolSheet is an external file that has been added as a reference. As Chris R says, have a look at the references, or failing that, try a search for VolSheet.

Comment: @ChrisR The line of code that fails is whatever first references VolSheet. There are no missing references. My first thought with all of this is that it was somehow embedded into the main worksheet as an object in Excel 2003, and Excel 2007 no longer recognizes it as an identifiable object.

It's used something like the following:
`Sheet1.VolSheet.Top = 2.25
Sheet1.VolSheet.Activate`
and etc.

Comment: @Remou I have searched for VolSheet within both the VBA project and within Excel's design mode. Neither has turned up any results.

Comment: I guess you have stepped through the code? Can you give the line on which the error occurs and a few lines around it, or the whole procedure, if it is not too large.

Comment: @Remou Mhmm, I have. The following block is where the error occurs. Whichever line references VolSheet first causes the error. No code before this in the SubRoutine uses VolSheet. _Error: Run-time error 424: Object required._ `VolSheet.TitleBar.Caption = Grade & " in " & Heading; VolSheet.Top = 2.25; VolSheet.Activate; VolSheet.Visible = True; VolSheet.Range("a7").Locked = False; VolSheet.Range("d3").Locked = False;` --snip-- _Semi-colons added for clarity._

Comment: It would help to know what type of object VolSheet is in the 2003 version.  One way to find out: run the app in 2003, open VBA editor and put a break point on the line of code that errors in 2007.  Run the code, and when it hits the break point, add a watch on VolSheet.  The watch window will tell you what the type is.  With this info we might have more insight into whats happening in 2007

Comment: @ChrisNeilsen As stated above in my question, Excel 2003 lists VolSheet as a Spreadsheet. Specifically in the watch, it's listed as a Spreadsheet/Spreadsheet.

Comment: 'Spreadsheet' is not a member of the Excel 2003 Object Model. Therefore it can only exists through some other mechanism, (eg by declaration, reference etc).  Is there a DIM statement for VolSheet?  In the Object browser which library is it a member of?

Comment: @ChrisNeilsen There is no Dim statement. It's a member of VBAProject.Entries. Entries is one of the worksheets in the Excel file.

Comment: An object is defined as a member of VBAProject.<Sheetname> when it is defined in VBA on the worksheet.  Can you post whatever, if any, code that is in the Entries sheet module.

Comment: @ChrisNeilsen No, I cannot post any code from the Entries sheet module. That being said, it does not define or specify any types. It's mostly just updating and changing values within different ranges. Going back a topic to type 'Spreadsheet,' it's part of Office Web Components (OWC).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to update your install of OWC on the 2007 machine

Office Web Components version 11 initially did not support Office 2007, but was updated to add it in SP1.  See [Link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/937961) and [Link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947318) for a security patch.

Comment: I've tested this on a couple computers now (XP and Win7, although supposedly it's not supposed to work on Win7), and no luck so far. I've checked to ensure that the new version of OWC is listed in the References and is being used. Excel still fails to recognize VolSheet.

Comment: Are you sure you have to Sp applied? 
File name File version
Msvcm80.dll 8.0.50727.762
Msvcp80.dll 8.0.50727.762
Msvcr80.dll 8.0.50727.762
Ogl.dll 12.0.6211.1000
Owc11.dll 12.0.6211.1000
Riched20.dll 12.0.6211.1000

Comment: I downloaded and installed owc2007sp1-kb937961-fullfile-en-us.exe from the first Microsoft link you gave me. Msvcm80.dll 8.0.50727.762 Msvcp80.dll 8.0.50727.762 Msvcr80.dll 8.0.50727.762 Ogl.dll 12.0.6211.1000 Owc11.dll 12.0.6211.1000 Riched20.dll 12.0.6211.1000

Comment: If it still doesn't work with OWC Sp1 then i'm stumped.  Without access to the actual excel files i really can't add any more (i guess that is out of the question!)

Comment: Mhmm, unfortunately it is. Thanks for the suggestions and your time, though. Much appreciated.